# Zuul proxy not routing

Tags: java, spring, netflix-zuul, netflix-eureka

While working on spring Microservices I am not able to route api through zuul proxy

This is my code

eurka:

application.yml

```
spring:
  application:
    name: api
  cloud:
    config:
      enabled: true

server:
  port: ${PORT:8761}


eureka:
  client:
    registerWithEureka: false
    fetchRegistry: false
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://${eureka.instance.hostname}:${server.port}/eureka/
  instance:
    hostname: localhost
```

zuul:

application.yml

```
spring:
  application:
    name: proxy-server

server:
  port: 8079

eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka
  fetchRegistry: true

zuul:
  ignored-services: '*'
  prefix: /api
  routes:
    account:
        path: /account/**
        serviceId: account
        stripPrefix: false
  host:
    socket-timeout-millis: 30000

ribbion:
  eureka:
    enabled: true
```

account
application.yml

```
ribbion:
  eureka:
    enabled: true


eureka:
  instance:
    preferIpAddress: true
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: ${EUREKA_URI:http://localhost:8761/eureka}
    instance:
      preferIpAddress: true
```

dependency:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>Finchley.SR1</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Now the url `localhost:8080/user/` is working fine but `localhost:8080/api/account/user/` is throwing a 404.

Not sure what wrong I am doing here, any insight will be helpful please let me know if you need other details

Comment: what is the route for the api/account/user on the downstream service?

Comment: its `localhost:8080/user` @shinjw

Comment: theres a route mismatch. the downstream service needs to be the fully qualified path. otherwise you'll need to manipulate the path via a ZuulFilter

Comment: Your Zuul proxy is on port `8079` not on port `8080`.

Comment: @shinjw can you provid and example please like with this url. I am following tutorials where it is said that `localhost:{zuulPort}/{prefix}/{serviceId}/{downstream Microservice url}`

Comment: Check if the accounts service is accepting requests on api/account/user/ endpoint. If it is account/user/, set stripPrefix to true.

Comment: @M.Deinum yes, and let me make the edit to question, but it is not working with that port either

Comment: actually account is accepting url without `account` in url

Comment: What is the `spring.application.name` for your `account` service? There isn't any in your `application.yml`. So is there actually an `account` service registered in Eureka.

Comment: the path needs to match downstream. your microservice controller would need to accept requests for `/api/account/user`. not `/user`

Comment: I changed  `stripPrefix: true` and now it is working fine. Just another quick, shall I build microservice for security or I should use zuul proxy service for security and authentication... Please let me know

Comment: thats entirely up to you

Comment: can anyone provide idea how to implement independently from zuul proxy, will be awsome :)

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is,

1. Generate a Spring boot project with Zuul as a dependency.
2. Annotate the main class with `@EnableZuulProxy`
3. Configure routes and endpoints in `application.properties` file
4. Build and start the service

I suggest to implement the above steps first and make them work. Then customize that project as per your need. Found below article explaining the above steps with more details.
[How to build an API-Gateway with Netflix Zuul + Spring Boot](https://devreads.xyz/how-to-build-an-api-gateway-with-netflix-zuul-spring-boot/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgotten to add the name the of account service in account application.yml

```
spring:
     application:
           name: account
```